# FluentValidation how to validate grandchild

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

Below is my 3 level class (Employee > Project > Teammate). I was able to validate the Status of the child (Project) wherein validate only if the list of projects is not empty.

However on the Teammate level, I dont know how to check for the TeamateName property.  Basically I wanted to do the same on the grandchild, if there are Teammates make sure to check the teammateName if empty or null.

Thanks!

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        

    public List<ProjectsDto> Projects { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectsDto
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
      
    public List<TeammatesDto> Teammates { get; set; }
}

public class TeammatesDto
{
    public string TeammateName { get; set; }
    public string PreviousProject { get; set; }
}

public class CreateEmployeeCommandValidator : AbstractValidator<CreateEmployeeCommand>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public CreateEmployeeCommandValidator(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;         

        RuleFor(v => v.Name)
            .NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required.")
            .MaximumLength(30).WithMessage("Name must not exceed 30 characters.");

        RuleFor(v => v.Projects)
            .ForEach(projectRule => {
                projectRule.Must(item => item.Status == null).WithMessage("Status is required");
            })
       .When(v => !StringUtil.IsNullOrEmptyList(v.Projects));

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and more organized option i think is the use of [SetValidator](https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/collections.html), you can use in a foreach rule, or just for child objects, so the code would be like this:

```
        RuleFor(v => v.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
                .WithMessage("Name is required.")
            .MaximumLength(30)
                .WithMessage("Name must not exceed 30 characters.");

        RuleForEach(v => v.Projects)
            .SetValidator(new YourProjectsValidator());
```

And inside YourProjectsValidator you will have the call to the Teammates validator like this:

```
RuleForEach(v => v.Teammates)
            .SetValidator(new YourTeammatesValidator());
```